# Rotate image using SVD in Python

Tags: python, math, image-rotation, svd

I would like to take several rotated images of a rectangular room like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL92t.png) and rotate them such that the long side of the room is parallel to the x-axis like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGwDu.png) in Python. A friend recommended using SVD, and from what I understand I need to use the Numpy or SciPy SVD, find the angle difference between the image and the x-axis, and rotate the image by the angle difference. I do not fully understand SVD, so what do I do once I have gotten the SVD?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVD is similar to PCA, it will find the "natural" axes in your data (read wikipedia or any other doco for more rigorous explanation of what "natural" means). The `U` matrix returned by SVD is the rotation matrix you are after (that is between the original x-y axis of your data, and the "natural" axes found by SVD).

Comment: Thanks, I looked up SVD and read that in the case where you have a square matrix the `U` matrix can be viewed as a rotation matrix. Since my image will be rectangular how do I use the `U` matrix? Do I multiply `U` and the image matrix?